# How to prove that a 8x8 chessboard is impossible to fill with domino if I remove 2 white squares and 2 black squares from the chessboard?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, tiling, chessboard

I have a 8x8 chessboard, that I can fill with dominos. But I need to prove that if I remove 2 white squares and 2 black squares, I'll be not capable of filling it with dominoes.

Comment: You can't. If you remove a 2x2 square from one corner, you can cover the rest of chessboard by dominos. You need to put some constraint on what black/white square to be removed.

Comment: "how to proof" -> "how to prove"

Comment: "But I need to prove that if ..." Why do you need to prove it?  Are they going to break your legs if you don't?  ... Well, I have bad news for you.  You can't prove something that isn't true.  ... Cover a full chess board with dominos, remove two.  Cut out the two black and white squares exposed.  The board with two black and white square removed.... is covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you **can** cover the chessbord then with domino pieces, **with one obvious exception**: when a corner of the board was not removed, but its two closest neighbours were removed. This was proved by [Colin Wright](https://www.keele.ac.uk/scm/staff/teachingfellows/colinwright/).

Comment: Can you post a link to the proof rather than just to his webpage?

Comment: I don't think he ever published it. He says [here](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/cgi-bin/sews.py?TheMutilatedChessBoard), after stating it: “I'll leave the details to the interested reader. I've yet to find a truly elegant argument (and would be interested in seeing one. Please.) ”

Comment: lol. I'm so dumb! Haha. Thank you.